# Parsing binary search as an arraylist in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, binary-search

### Is there any possible way to make this code shorter?

---

```
            int? index = ListOfPeople.BinarySearch(searchBar.Text);
            int? temp = int.TryParse(index.ToString(), out int i) ? (int?)1 : null;
            MyPeopleGrid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
            MyPeopleGrid.Rows[i].Selected = true;
            MyPeopleGrid.CurrentCell = MyPeopleGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have seriously overcomplicated things, and you certainly should never convert a number to a string only to parse it back to a number.

```
int index = ListOfPeople.BinarySearch(searchBar.Text);
```

This will return a non-negative number when the item isn't found. It does not return `int?`, it returns `int`.

So now you can use it:

```
int index = ListOfPeople.BinarySearch(searchBar.Text);
if (index >= 0)
{
    MyPeopleGrid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
    MyPeopleGrid.Rows[index].Selected = true;
    MyPeopleGrid.CurrentCell = MyPeopleGrid.Rows[index].Cells[0];
}
else
{
    // do something when the item isn't found
}
```

Comment: I need that int i, otherwise this code not working `gdv.CurrentCell = gdv.Rows[i].Cells[0];`

Comment: OK, what are you actually trying to do then?  Why do you need a nullable int? What's that for?

Comment: After searching with the BinarySeach it select the row.

Comment: With that code I posted is working totally fine, but I am curious if there is a shorter way for that code.

Comment: Can you post some more code? I don't understand why you're not just using `ArrayList.BinarySearch(searchBar.Text);` without the extra stuff.

Comment: What are you using `temp` for?